# css flex or grid 4 columns having one column with the width of 85%

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am having trouble with flex grading of 4 columns and one column with almost full width
the image is Figma design
[flexbox gridding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCIQp.png)
it's not important to implement in flex or grid.

```css
.product {
  direction: rtl;
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px #3976b7 solid;
  padding: 5px;
  /* this */
}

.product>div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px #3976b7 solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  /* and that, will result in a 10px gap */
}

.product.mc
/* multicol test */

{
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product mc">
  <div><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png" height="15px" width="35px"></div>
  <div clas="title">taste our fresh chips</div>
  <div>$40</div>
  <div><a href="">Add to cart</a></div>
```

Comment: flex: 1 1 auto; auto mean automatic sizing. if you want exactly 4 columns change auto to 25%

Comment: @Sfili_81 thanks for that tip, but I don't want them with the same sizes, as you can see in image.

Comment: Ooops i misunderstood sorry :(